# How to auto logOut in Next.js app router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I am using credentials in Next.js app-router, i am using next-auth to login which is working fine but let's suppose my token is expired i want to auto log out od the web app, but the my session is saving the token and not checkng for token expiration. I am new to Next.js can anyone help me out here .

This is my login body :

```
{
  name: 'Anuj',
  email: 'admin@gmail.com',
  sub: '1',
  id: 1,
  role: 'ADMIN',
  token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwiZW1haWwiOiJhZG1pbkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE3MTAwODEyMzUsImV4cCI6MTcxMDA4MTI1MH0.DHGdFCdytlRrXdKvgxYBVhOpjcNtbJVoeYBRcIKeJrk',
  iat: 1710083082,
  exp: 1712675082,
  jti: 'bba219c1-b2bb-416b-8bb8-9322db732b83'
}
```

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import CredentialProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [

    CredentialProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
        console.log("credentials", credentials);

        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/v1/user/login", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
        }).then((res) => res.json());

        // const user = { id: "1", name: "John", email: credentials?.email };
        console.log("user", response);

        if (response?.status === 200) {
          return { ...response.data };
        } else if (response?.status === 422) {
          throw new Error(response.message);
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },

    }),

  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }: { token: any, user: any }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.name = "Anuj";
        token.email = user.email;
        token.role = user.userRole;
        token.token = user.token;
      }
      return token;

    },
    async session({ session, token }: { session: any, token: any }) {
      console.log("session ---> ", session, token);

      session.id = token.id;
      session.name = "Anuj";
      session.email = token.email;
      session.role = token.role;
      session.token = token.token;
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/", //sigIn page,
  },
};
```

```
  const onSubmit = async (data: UserFormValue) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await signIn("credentials", {
        redirect: false,
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
        // callbackUrl: callbackUrl ?? "/dashboard",
      });
      console.log("response", response);

      if (response?.ok) {
        router.push("/dashboard");
      } else if (!response?.ok && response?.error === "fetch failed") {
        // set the error message to the form for something like network error
        form.setError("email", { message: "Network error" });
        form.setError("password", { message: "Network error" });
      } else {
        form.setError("email", { message: response?.error ?? "Invalid credentials" });
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error", error);
      // check if error is of type InvalidCredentialsError or something else
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

<Form {...form}>
        <form
          onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          className="space-y-2 w-full"
        >
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="email"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Enter your email..."
                    disabled={loading}
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />

          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="password"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Enter your password..."
                    disabled={loading}
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />

          {/* <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
            <Checkbox
              disabled={loading}
              name="remember"
              control={form.control}
            />

            <label className="text-muted-foreground">Remember me</label>
          </div> */}
          <Button disabled={loading} className="ml-auto w-full" type="submit">
            Sign In {loading && "..."}
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Form>
```

I tried checking token using

```
const checkIfTokenExpired = Date.now() > token.exp * 1000;
```

but it is returning false, but my token is expired. I am confused ..

Comment: The token in your login body is at least not expired. The attribute `exp` has as value the numer `1712675082` and `new Date(1712675082000)` gives `Tuesday, 9th April 2024, 15:04:42 (GMT)`

Comment: Yes, on login i am getting new token but, let's say the token get's expired later on and i am in dashboard component having no backend ap's calling ... then the system won't be triggered to logOut. Token expired then no static component page also rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not attach the expiration time in your jwt callback. Please modify your code like below

```
async jwt({ token, user }: { token: any, user: any }) {
    if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.name = "Anuj";
        token.email = user.email;
        token.role = user.userRole;
        token.token = user.token;

        const decodedToken = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(user.token.split(".")[1], "base64").toString())

        if (decodedToken) {
            token.tokenExpires = decodedToken["exp"] * 1000
        }
    }

    if (token.tokenExpires && (Date.now() > Number(token.tokenExpires))) {
        // the token is expired
        console.log("The token is expired!")
        return {
            ...token,
            error: "AccessTokenError"
        }
    }

    return token
},
async session({ session, token }: { session: any, token: any }) {
    return {
        ...session,
        user: {
            ...session.user,
            id: token.id,
            name: token.name,
            email: token.email,
            role: token.role,
            token: token.token,
            tokenExpires: token.tokenExpires,
        },
        error: token.error,
    }
}
```